# iOS amazon uploading video using S3

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading video to amazon bucket it works fine it uplaodes the file also shows the file size but it does not show any file extension and when i download the file it just show text file.

It should show the video file as it shows the size correct does not show file.

here is the code i am using.

```
 -(IBAction)uploadPhotoWithGrandCentralDispatch:(id)sender
  {
     [self showImagePicker:GrandCentralDispatch];
  }

  - (void)processGrandCentralDispatchUpload:(NSData *)imageData

 {

  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

  dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    // Upload image data.  Remember to set the content type.
    S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:PICTURE_NAME
                                                              inBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]] autorelease];
 //   por.contentType = @"image/jpeg";

    por.contentType =@"movie/mov";




    por.data = imageData;


    // Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.
    S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [self.s3 putObject:por];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if(putObjectResponse.error != nil)
        {




            NSLog(@"Error: %@", putObjectResponse.error);
            [self showAlertMessage:[putObjectResponse.error.userInfo objectForKey:@"message"] withTitle:@"Upload Error"];
        }
        else





        {

//                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataDoneLoading:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataDoneLoading:) withObject:imageData waitUntilDone:NO];


            [self showAlertMessage:@"The image was successfully uploaded." withTitle:@"Upload Completed"];




        }



        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
     });
    });
    }

#pragma mark - AmazonServiceRequestDelegate

-(IBAction)uploadPhotoWithDelegate:(id)sender
{

 [self showImagePicker:Delegate];


}

- (void)processDelegateUpload:(NSData *)imageData
{
// Upload image data.  Remember to set the content type.
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:PICTURE_NAME
                                                          inBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]] autorelease];
//por.contentType = @"image/jpeg";

//Madi work///
por.contentType =@"movie/mov";


por.data = imageData;
por.delegate = self;

// Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.
[self.s3 putObject:por];
}

   -(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:    (AmazonServiceResponse *)response

 {
   [self showAlertMessage:@"The image was successfully uploaded." withTitle:@"Upload Completed"];

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

   }


 -(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

 {

 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
[self showAlertMessage:error.description withTitle:@"Upload Error"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

 }
```

## pragma mark - Background Thread

```
-(IBAction)uploadPhotoWithBackgroundThread:(id)sender
{
[self showImagePicker:BackgroundThread];
}

- (void)processBackgroundThreadUpload:(NSData *)imageData
{
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(processBackgroundThreadUploadInBackground:)
                       withObject:imageData];
}

- (void)processBackgroundThreadUploadInBackground:(NSData *)imageData

{
// Upload image data.  Remember to set the content type.
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:PICTURE_NAME
                                                          inBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]] autorelease];
// por.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
 por.contentType = @"movie/mov";

por.data        = imageData;

// Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.
S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [self.s3 putObject:por];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showCheckErrorMessage:)
                       withObject:putObjectResponse.error
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)showCheckErrorMessage:(NSError *)error
{
if(error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [self showAlertMessage:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"message"] withTitle:@"Upload Error"];
}
else
{
    [self showAlertMessage:@"The image was successfully uploaded." withTitle:@"Upload Completed"];
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
   }
```

## pragma mark - Show the image in the browser

```
-(IBAction)showInBrowser:(id)sender
 {
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    // Set the content type so that the browser will treat the URL as an image.
    S3ResponseHeaderOverrides *override = [[[S3ResponseHeaderOverrides alloc] init] autorelease];
    //override.contentType = @"image/jpeg";


    override.contentType = @"movie/mov";
    // Request a pre-signed URL to picture that has been uplaoded.
    S3GetPreSignedURLRequest *gpsur = [[[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    gpsur.key                     = PICTURE_NAME;
    gpsur.bucket                  = [Constants pictureBucket];
    gpsur.expires                 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval) 3600]; // Added an hour's worth of seconds to the current time.
    gpsur.responseHeaderOverrides = override;

    // Get the URL
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [self.s3 getPreSignedURL:gpsur error:&error];

    if(url == nil)
    {
        if(error != nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self showAlertMessage:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"message"] withTitle:@"Browser Error"];
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Display the URL in Safari
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        });
    }

});
  }
```

## pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods

```
 -(void) dataDoneLoading:(id) obj {

[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

}

-(void)uploadAllData :(id) obj{
[self processGrandCentralDispatchUpload:imageData];
}
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
 // Get the selected image.

//  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// Convert the image to JPEG data.

NSURL *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

//  imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
 imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:image];
if(_uploadType == GrandCentralDispatch)
{
    alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uploading Data\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    indicator.center = CGPointMake(150, 100);
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [alert addSubview:indicator];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(uploadAllData:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}
else if(_uploadType == Delegate)
{
    [self processDelegateUpload:imageData];
}
else if(_uploadType == BackgroundThread)
{
    [self processBackgroundThreadUpload:imageData];
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set your content type to video/quicktime instead of movie/mov in both places you are setting it and update your PICTURE_NAME variable to have the extension .mov that should solve your issue.